# Asking whether this question will be suitable and hence answered by people on MO ? ( I will use career and advice tag)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I am thinking of asking this question on the MO website which is due to the fact that how should I write/ explain the gap in my CV while applying for PHD programs in 2022.

Very brief of the situations that happened from  Jan 2021. Living in a 3rd word country ( I will add full details if I am allowed to ask on MO) : I completed my masters in math in Jun 2020. Then I wanted to study some additional topics before applying in Europe. So, took 1 year break and went home. studied fine till Jan 2021 , then verbal abuse stated by my father and occasionally by my mother( They earlier also used to verbal  abuse me but I didn't did my bachelors and masters in my native city, so less impact was on me). Admitted to mental hospital for a 10 days in Feb and misdiagnosed with skiezoprenia( I have depression). Verbal and emotional abuse continues and again admitted to different hospital in march end for 11 days, diagnosed for depression. Verbal abuse again continues after some days of discharge. So, I move out taking a part time job to sustain myself in different city on 1 July and learning some new math topics alongside. Thinking about suicide since March 2021 but postponed to try 1 more year if I am not able to get a phd position as learning and doing math is the only thing I like. ( Reason of verbal abuse:  Parents wanted me to do full time job and not math research so that I can settle early and also wanted me to take a career like medical doctor or engineer which is more earning and takes less time to settle time). I could only study 1 month of math in these 6 months.

Question which I am about to post on MO : How much should I mention the situation due to my 6 months are being wasted in my CV when applying to PHD position in Mathematics ? Will the admittion by my that I have suffered from depression affect my selection for Phd? I don't think I should lie as I would be really  wierd to make up what I was not  doing as what I was doing. I really need advice.

> So,Is this question suitable for MO?

Comment: Your question is probably not suitable for MO. But also, I think almost nobody cares about any "gap" in activites. No need to explain anything.

Comment: There's a site, https://academia.stackexchange.com/ – I'm not familiar with it, but maybe have a look at it, see whether it seems suitable.

Comment: I do not think that you should explain anything in your scientific CV about depression or more generally any kind of illness. But the most important thing is that you try to *take care* of yourself. I agree that your question is probably not suitable for MO, but maybe it is for academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: As other comments mentioned, AcademiaSE is a more suitable place for such questions. By the way, know that you are not alone and [depression is very common amongst graduate students and faculty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28258/48776). And please consider seeking help for suicidal thoughts. Hope you get back on track soon. (The AcademiaSE community is very supportive and hopefully, you'll find some good advice there. Such as [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31855) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/138747))

Comment: I'd mention more why and how you like doing math: what area of math? what style of proof? what kinds of calculation? with what role models? By contrast, I'd avoid mentioning the personal situation in any written documents. Anyone wondering may assume it was a Covid interruption; if they ask more in conversation, you can mention hospitalization and a bad family situation, and then get back to the math.